# How to display a message when a selectbox value is select?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

For instance , a selectbox has 3 options

> a, b,c

each one has a message assign

a : message for a

b : message for b

c : message for c

What i would like to achieve is when the optiton select , the message will be display next to the selectbox, when the optiton value change, the message will be changed at the same time. The messages are stored in an array

Thank you.

Here is the link of a selectbox, it is not simple selectbox though, as there are three option in each three select box, when a option is selected , that option in the rest of the selectbox will be disabled

http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/M33N9/

Comment: This could be done in a number of ways.  What approach are you looking for?  Sample code would be helpful, as well.

Comment: Could you post some of your post? Would help us help you!

Comment: Show use you page, we don't even know what your select box name is or anything.

Comment: @user782104-Please try to understand what the comments are about.we are asking about you coding part.If you show us you will be getting much more help from us.

Comment: Why do you have three selects. Very confusing.

Comment: @iambriansreed  It is an example, showing there are 3 select box for opt a , b , c . if opt a select in select box 1 , the select box 2, 3, will not allow to choose opt a, hope you understand, thanks.

Comment: @user782104 Still don't get it; why three checkboxes? Can you provide a little context? Also if my answer below answered your original question please accept it.

Comment: The number of check box is not fix , but if three checkboxes there must be three optitions. So that if checkbox a select optition b, then optition b can not be selected from checkbox b  and c.

Comment: This is a different matter. Please create a new question with sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof:

http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/G7Lvx/

HTML:

```
<select>
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
</select>
​<div id="message"></div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

JavaScript:

```
var messages = {
    a: 'Armadillo',
    b: 'Bear',
    c: 'Cougar'
}
$('select').change(function() {
    $('#message').text(messages[$(this).val()]);
});​
```

Comment: This works, however, i am wondering how to dynamic add javascript using php? for example, i have to set rules "sel1.onchange = 
disableOpts(this)" for each selectbox. I want to use php to get the total number of select box and add the javascript, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Change to this

```
(var i = 0, len = elem.length; i < len; i++)
```

from this:

```
(var i = 0, len = sels.length; i < len; i++)
```

Comment: your question title, and requirement are quite different. can't help much. :(

Answer (score 0):

change your select box to have as value the position of message in your array for example when it shows A, then in change event you can get the message

```
$('Yourselect').change(function(){
var msg = YourArray[$(this).val()];
// Show it wherever yu want
});
```